# Можно ли изменить внешний вид запроса на использование камеры/микрофона в браузере?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Можно ли изменить внешний вид запроса на использование камеры/микрофона в браузере?
например изменить иконки, расположение кнопок?

Comment: Нельзя :) Но можно *дополнительно* показывать что захотите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это которое браузерное? 
Ответ - нет

Но, быть может, какая-нибудь магия имеется, но я в этом очень сомневаюсь, ибо небезопасно

Можно конечно свой браузер сделать, но это уже другая история...

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/464373)

Comment: @S.Nick #панимаю